# Facebook API 2.0 Update

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have seen that the old Facebook SDK won't be working for FB login on April 30th. And I want to make sure my apps aren't going to start failing, on this date. On my iOS app I have under the FB framework I see this in the header file `Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0` and then in the android app in the Facebook android manifest I see this `Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");` But then on my developers Facebook page when I go to my app and I look at API Version I see 1.0. but I am pretty sure that the header files in my projects say I'm in 2.0. Can anyone help, me is there a way to check for sure?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

That's about the License version, not the API version! If you didn't change any of your code, it's very likely you're still using v1.0.

Have a look at the upgrading guides here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2

Comment: So does this mean changing the framework in iOS and the module in android?

Comment: If you mean updating the SDK then yes

Comment: I don't want to update SDK just, the API version. Im looking at the guide but am still bit confused